# Strange spacing between an inputAccessoryView and a keyboard

Tags: swift

I have an `InitialView` that contains an `AccessoryView` (blue rectangle at the bottom) as a subview.

[image: InitialViewController]

When I tap to this `AccessoryView`, `InitialViewController` presents `OverlayViewController` without animation (sounds like a very ugly solution, but in a real project it makes sense):

```
let overlayViewController = OverlayViewController()
overlayViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
present(overlayViewController, animated: false)
```

`OverlayViewController` has an `inputAccessoryView` (`accessoryViewController.rootView` is `AccessoryView` like on `InitialView`):

```
override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool { true }
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? { accessoryViewController.rootView }
```

This `inputAccessoryView` presents on `viewWillAppear(animated:)`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

After that, TextView becomes the first responder on `viewDidAppear(animated:)`:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    accessoryViewController.rootView.textView.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

However, sometimes when the keyboard appears, there is a strange glitch where there is some space between the `inputAccessoryView` and the keyboard.

[image: Bug]

Could you help me to remove this spacing? This is my first experience with `inputAccessoryView` and it is really hard for me to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It looks to me like the gap is the size of the bottom margin of the safeArea. Is your rootView pinned to the safeAreaLayoutGuide or to the bottom of the containing view? You may want to play around with some varitaions.

Comment: @RobC thanks for your answer! RootView is a just a view of viewController with a concrete type. `view = rootView` on `loadView()`. I didn't add any additional constraints to rootView.

Comment: I'm curious how you added your accessoryViewController to the viewController stack. You didn't talk about much in your post. Is it a child view controller of your overlay view controller?

Comment: @RobC I added accessoryViewController as `inputAccessoryViewController` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the problem was elsewhere. I added a transparent button to my `AccessoryView` and added target on `.touchDown` event.

`InitialViewController`:

```
rootView.accessoryView.backgroundButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openOverlayScreen), for: .touchDown)
```

When I changed `.touchDown` to `.touchUpInside` the problem is went away.